# constexpr uintptr_t : expression must have constant value

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constexpr

I just learned about constexpr in C++ and intended to use it in a project.

But I already stamble on a compilor error : `expression must have constant value` with this code :

```cpp
constexpr uintptr_t addr1 = 0x00400000;
constexpr uintptr_t addr2 = addr1 + 0x0346DC48;
```

[image: image of the error in visual studio]

As `uintptr_t` is just a `typedef unsigned int uintptr_t`, I tried with `unsigned int` instead and didn't get the error anymore :

```cpp
constexpr unsigned int addr1 = 0x00400000;
constexpr uintptr_t addr2 = addr1 + 0x0346DC48;
```

Anyone knows why and is willing to explain it ?

---

Edit1 : This is for 32 bit build

---

Edit2 : Adding an import like `windows.h`, `iostream` or `stdlib.h` solves the issue (I tested many includes and they all solved the issue). But I don't understand why.

Comment: `typedef unsigned int uintptr_t` no that's not true. It'll likely be `typedef unsigned long uintptr_t` or `typedef unsigned long long uintptr_t` in a 64-bit build

Comment: The program [works here](https://godbolt.org/z/Tjeq3q1f5) in all compilers.

Comment: @phuclv I forgot to mention the build is 32 bit.

Comment: @JasonLiam Indeed that works. I might have forgotten the import. But I don't understand why this would cause this issue.

Comment: In my copy of Visual Studio I also get a red squiggly under `uintptr_t`, where it offers to add the proper include. And then it works.

Comment: If you have not included any standard library header at all, then `uintptr_t` will be undeclared and compilation should already fail there. You _must_ include `<stdint.h>` (or better `<cstdint>` and then use `std::uintptr_t` instead) to assure that this compiles.

Comment: To find out which header to inlcude check cppreference.com e.g.  look for uintptr_t here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer. Then this site tells you this : `Defined in header <cstdint>`. The fact the it works after including any of the other header files is that they (indirectly) include `<cstdint>`

Comment: What I got is identifier "uintptr_t" is undefined. Did you add any header files to the code in your picture?

Comment: Can you  provide steps to reproduce the problem in your picture? Looks like an intellisense error.